# How to debug the Nashorn JavaScript use the IntelliJ IDEA debugger ？

Tags: javascript, java, debugging, intellij-idea, nashorn

I have clone this project. https://github.com/winterbe/java8-tutorial/
And I want to debug the project's Nashorn JavaScript file use the IntelliJ IDEA debugger.
I run the Nashorn9.java in debug model, and I want to add a breakpoint at nashorn9.js.
But it is not working. When I run the debug model, the breakpoint in the  nashorn9.js having been ignoreed.
The offical says the IDEA support this function after idea-13.
https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/debugger-for-jdk8s-nashorn-javascript-in-intellij-idea-13-1/#comment-421006

My envinments as follows:

IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.1
Build #IU-171.4073.35, built on April 7, 2017
JRE: 1.8.0_112-release-736-b16 x86_64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Mac OS X 10.11.6

Updated:
I have test some different verson IntelliJ IDEA.
Below is test results:

IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.4  not support.
IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.1  not support.
**IntelliJ IDEA 14.1.7  support.**

Comment: It's not working is not a problem description.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to mark `res` folder as a [resource root](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-projects.html#project_tool_window).

Works for me:
[image]

Comment: Which version is your IntelliJ IDEA ?  I test ideaIU-14.1.7 ,it is ok. But IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.1 and IntelliJ IDEA 2018.2.4 are not working.